# How can I create a link-list in order to test a method that uses a Node class?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I know that a linked-list contains nodes where each node stores a value and a reference to the next node. I've seen classes that use these Nodes (like Linked-list Stack and Queue) and I had no trouble understanding them. But I don't understand how these nodes are actually created. I've looked at tutorials and each tutorial looks like it's doing completely different things and so I find it hard to grasp the overall concept.

I have a Java method that uses a Node:

```
public Node fun(Node x) {
   Node first = x;
   Node magic = null;
   while (first != null) {
      Node second = first.next;
      first.next  = magic; 
      magic       = first;
      first       = second;
   }
   return magic;
}
```

I want to test this method. But in order to actually test this method, I need a linked-list (otherwise I'll get an error because Node is not recognized). This is where I'm lost. How do I create the Node class? Is the Node class and Linked-list class two entirely separate things? Is so, what would the linked-list class look like?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `Node` class is this :

```
class Node {
    int value;
    Node next;

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    // setters and getters
}
```

You can create a `linked list` in this way :

```
 Node first = new Node(0);
 first.next = new Node(1);
 first.next.next = new Node(2);
 first.next.next.next = new Node(3);
```

You can iterate through list:

```
while(first != null) {
    System.out.println(first.value);
    first = first.next;
}
```

Comment: So the linked list is a separate class?

Comment: @TheSaviour - the linked-list class does not exist in this case. ``first`` is the head of the list, you can get all the data from it.

Comment: But how can it be applied to the method shown above?

Comment: @Thesaviour , what do you mean ?  you just take ``first`` node and iterate while it's not is null, every time assigning the ``next`` node

Comment: `Node first = new Node(0);
 first.next = new Node(1);
 first.next.next = new Node(2);
 first.next.next.next = new Node(3);`

Comment: But should this code be in the Node class or in a separate class?